# Multiple lists merge in to single list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, jquery

I have 3 lists

```
Initiatives
-----------
Initiative (single line text)

Themes
------
Theme      (single line text)
Initiative (Lookup from Initiatives:Initiative)


Features
--------
Feature    (single line text)
Theme      (Lookup from Themes:Theme)
```

Now i want to display the data in a page in the below manner using OOB feature or code.

```
•Initiative 1                                     
◦Theme 1.1 
■Features 1.1.1 
■Features 1.1.2 
■Features 1.1.3 
■Features 1.1.4 
■Features 1.1.5 

◦Theme 1.2 

■Features 1.2.1 
■Features 1.2.2 
■Features 1.2.3 
■Features 1.2.4 
■Features 1.2.5 
◦Theme 2.1 
■Features 2.1.1 
■Features 2.1.2 
■Features 2.1.3 
■Features 2.1.4 
■Features 2.1.5 
◦Theme 2.2 
■Features 2.2.1 
■Features 2.2.2 
■Features 2.2.3 
■Features 2.2.4 
■Features 2.2.5
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Is this just for reporting purposes? What sort of additional functionality would be required? In-line editing, etc?

Comment: No I just want to show it in a share point custom page. Product is sharepoint 2010

Comment: Any quick help is much appreciated please

Answer (score 1):

So far i tried like this i think i am close to a solution but unable to display the data with in the tree view.

```
Countries
-----------
CountryName(single line text)

States
------
StateName     (single line text)
CountryName(Lookup from Countries:CountryName)


City
--------
CityName    (single line text)
StateName   (Lookup from StateName:States)
```

Attached Jpg([image: sample list data here] is sample data from all the 3 lists. 
Now i have written three methods (one to get all countries, one that gets states by countryid, and one for cities by stateid) something like this:

```
public static SPListItemCollection GetCountries()
        {
            SPListItemCollection items;

            SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            items = web.Lists["Countries"].GetItems();
            return items;
        }

        public SPListItemCollection GetStates(int countryID)
        {
            SPListItemCollection items;
            SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            string queryString = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"CountryName\" LookupId=\"True\" /><Value Type=\"Lookup\">" + countryID + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery(web.Lists["States"].DefaultView);
            query.Query = queryString;
            items = web.Lists["States"].GetItems(query);
            return items;
        }

        public SPListItemCollection GetCities(int stateid)
        {
            SPListItemCollection items;
            SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            string queryString = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"StateName\" LookupId=\"True\" /><Value Type=\"Lookup\">" + stateid + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery(web.Lists["City"].DefaultView);
            query.Query = queryString;
            items = web.Lists["City"].GetItems(query);
            return items;
        }
```

I tried to display the data in the tree view but it is displaying with the Column name Instead of data in that column name . Screen shot below.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace TreeViewProject.TreeViewWebpart
{
    public partial class TreeViewWebpartUserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SPListItemCollection countries = GetCountries();
            foreach (SPItem country in countries)
            {

                TreeNode nodeCountry = new TreeNode(country.Fields["CountryName"].ToString(), country.ID.ToString(), null, "", "_self");
                mytree.Nodes.Add(nodeCountry);
                SPListItemCollection states = GetStates(country.ID);

                foreach (SPItem state in states)
                {
                    TreeNode nodeState = new TreeNode(state.Fields["StateName"].ToString(), country.ID.ToString(), null, "", "_self");
                    nodeCountry.ChildNodes.Add(nodeState);
                    SPListItemCollection cities = GetCities(state.ID);
                    foreach (SPItem city in cities)
                    {
                        TreeNode nodeCity = new TreeNode(city.Fields["CityName"].ToString(), city.ID.ToString(), null, "", "_self");
                        nodeState.ChildNodes.Add(nodeCity);
                    } } }}
```

Can you please help how to modify this code to display with the correct data from the list.
[image] like the below format

Comment: I think i made a mistake .. i was able to solve this issue by city.Fields["CityName"].ToString() to city["CityName"].ToString(). Robert can you please help me to display this in the grid view as which you have poasted below

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply. There are a couple of different ways to approach this. Personally I would use `ListData.svc` and jQuery for this. I tend to use Kendo UI for my frontend work but you could use jQuery UI or just roll your own template with CSS.

Here is an example jQuery call to `ListData.svc`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    successFunction(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    errorFunction(jqXHR);
});
```

There are some things you have to lookout for when using REST in SharePoint 2010.

1. List names are all together Pascal case. So a list titled "Work Items" would be accessed via the URL `../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/WorkItems`.
2. Field names are **based on the title**, not the internal name. So on the server-side where you would use `item["Author"]` to get the person who created the item, via the 2010 REST service it is `Created`. The best advice I have for you in this is to use a tool like `Dev HTTP Client` for Chrome that can let you craft the HTTP request and see the JSON that you get back.
3. Use `$expand` and `$select` and [other operators for filtering](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/), etc.

Here is an example of a grid that I have on a production site in SharePoint 2010 using [Kendo UI grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) and the `ListData.svc`. I blurred the document titles a little since the might be sensitive.

[image]

Here is the code used to generate that grid. Note that I am useing MVVM to declare the grid. You would likely just want to use the programmatic method explained in the Kendo UI API reference.

```
psApp.releasedProcesses = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        autoSync: false,
        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize:10,
        group: { field: "OwnersGroup", aggregates: [ { field: "OwnersGroup", aggregate: "count" } ] },
        aggregate: [ { field: "OwnersGroup", aggregate: "count" } ],
        pageable: true,
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ReleasedProcesses?&orderby=OwnersGroup&$inlinecount=allpages",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: options.data
                }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    options.success(data);
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    options.error(jqXHR);
                });
            }
        }
});

<div id="released-grid-view"
    data-role="grid"
    data-selectable="single"
    data-auto-bind="true"
    data-pagesize="15"
    data-pageable="{ pagesize: 15, pageSizes: [10,15,20,25], refresh:true}"
    data-columns='[  
        { 
            "field": "ProcessDocID", 
            "title": "Title",
            "template":  kendo.template($("#rel-title-column").html())
        },  
        {
            "field": "DocumentRev", 
            "title": "Revision",
            "width": "100px"
        },  
        {
            "field": "DocTypeValue", 
            "title": "Doc Type",
            "width": "100px"
        },  
        {
            "field": "OwnersGroup",
            "title": "Owner Group",
            "groupHeaderTemplate": "#= value # (#= count#)"
        },
        {  
            "field": "Modified",
            "title": "Last Modified",
            "template":  kendo.template($("#created-column").html()),
            "width": "120px",
            "filterable": {
                "ui": "datepicker",
                extra: false,
                operators: {
                    date: {
                        eq: "Is equal to",
                        neq: "Is not equal to",
                        gte: "Is after or equal to",
                        gt: "Is after",
                        lte: "Is before or equal to",
                        lt: "Is before"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ]'
    data-scrollable="true"
    data-filterable="true"
    data-sortable="true"
    data-source="psApp.releasedProcesses" 
></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-ui-template" id="rel-title-column">
   <div class="grid-title">
      <a href="${__metadata.media_src}">
    <img style="height:25px;" src="icons/office/pdf-small.png" > ${Title}
      </a>
   </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-ui-template" id="created-column">
      #= moment(Created).format("MM/DD/YYYY")#
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a data view in designer.

Create a new data source in designer. I forget which option it is but it lets you combine lists into a single data source. Then add an empty dataview to a page and attach that new data source to it.

Hope this pushes you in the right direction.

[Display data from multiple sources in a single Data View](http://en.hugon.ws/articles/sharepoint-2007/display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-data-view/)

Edit:
Per Roberts recommendation here is a high level summary of the steps based on the blog he was kind enough to link.

- In SharePoint Designer create a new Linked Data Source by selecting Data Sources and then the Linked Data Source button on the ribbon.
- Give your new data source a name and under the general tab of the pop
  up window specify the lists you want to link.
- Click next then select the type of merge you want to do.  The two
  options are explained pretty well on the page, but i believe if you
  want to join all items its the first option.
- Click finish and your new data source will be created and ready.
- Open a new web part page or other type of page in SharePoint Designer
  and edit it (you may have to detach it from the layout in order to
  make these changes.)
- Click anywhere in an editable area of the page and on the Insert tab
  click the drop down on the Data View button and select Empty Data
  View.
- From there, you will see your page update and you will be shown a
  link on the data view to select the data source.  Click the link and
  connect the data view to your new data source.
- From here its like working with a normal data view.  Select the
  fields you want to display on the Data Source Details window and use
  the formatting, filtering, and other options on the Data View Tools /
  Options menu to tweak your display.

PS. As an added note, if you ever want to add groupings of more than two levels to a view, you can use the same process but link to your list rather than a custom data source.  The data view web part gives you a bit more functionality than the default views give you.

Comment: That is actually how I used to do this in SharePoint 2007. I tend to find it a bit to cumbersome now-a-days, though. I like having the freedom you get when using HTML5/CSS.

Comment: I added a link to a blog post to your answer. If you wanted to improve it a little more, it's common to give a high-level overview of the steps for the answer to be acceptable (once my edit appears). If you add a bit of detail, I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Robert, thank you. I dont have the required points to post comments yet which is why i posted it as an answer.  Thanks for linking the blog.  I have updated the answer to give a brief summary of what needs to be done.  And by the way, i love KendoUI and SPServices.  I use them all the time when able and i do find at times its a much more elegant solution.  Grouping and getting a view to look the way you need it in SharePoint Designer can be a tedious task, kendo makes it look good out of the box.